# Is it possible to upgrade an existing IaaS VM OS image from 2012 to 2016

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have several IaaS Vms deployed with windows 2012 datacenter. Is it possible to upgrade to 2016 without re-creating VM?

Comment: Confirmed with Azure support, you are right, the in-place OS upgrade is not supported yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, OS upgrades of Azure VMs are not supported by Microsoft.

Refer to this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2721672/microsoft-server-software-support-for-microsoft-azure-virtual-machines),

> Microsoft does not support an upgrade of the operating system of a Microsoft Azure virtual machine. Instead, you should create a new Azure virtual machine that is running the supported version of the operating system that is required and then migrate the workload.

Besides, this is the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/18691129-support-upgrading-existing-azure-vm-with-windows-s) of the similar issue of upgrades from 2012 R2 to 2016, you could vote it or post another specific ideal.